# How to overload functions from a PHP extension?

Tags: php, php-internals

I've been going through some PHP extension tutorials, but I can't find any information about how to overload existing function.

For example, I want to change the fopen() to something like

```
PHP_FUNCTION(fopen)
{
    if condition_is_true(condition)
        original_fopen();
    else
        show_error();
}
```

How could I do that?
Thank you

PS. I mean the extension (written in C, compiled to .so and included in httpd.conf, not the .php program)

---

**Edit: Found a solution, thanks to Gordon links.**

I have downloaded PECL package for function `rename_function`. Its source code has led me to the required conclusions:

- There is global hash table `function_table`, which holds all the pointers for functions, based on their names.
- `zend_hash_find`/`zend_hash_add`/`zend_hash_del` will allow me to do whatever changes I want in this table.

Comment: I seriously doubt you'd be allowed to do that.  It would cause holy hell for some function built into PHP to suddenly behave differently from expected

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Zend Framework then all requests go through the same bootstrap file (usually `index.php` in your public directory)

You can use this to create a new php file called `my_global_functions.php` and include it like

```
require_once "my_global_functions.php"
```

now just create a new function there like

```
function my_fopen(){ 
    if condition_is_true(condition)
        fopen();
    else
        show_error();        
}
```

you should be able to call `my_fopen` from anywhere in your code now.

Comment: I have added note to my question, to clarify it a bit: I mean the extension (written in C, compiled to .so and included in httpd.conf, not the .php script)